# CEP for edge computing

Tags: cloud, iot, complex-event-processing, stream-processing

In an IoT plataform, I need to define some rule-based behaviour, configured by domain experts through Web UIs. I have device measurments/events flowing through MQTT channels from IoT gateways to cloud, but I would prefer evaluate rules on edge instead of send more data to cloud. I'm looking for some tool that offers a DSL to write rules and write a minimal glue-code to collect the data that is evaluated. I know few of them (Apache Strom, Drools, Something done with Akka Streams) but it seems that are meant for cloud/distribuited environments, where scalability and fault tolerance are the most important aspects; on the other hand an edge computing app should just have low resource consumption, no scalability and fully configurable from remote.

[image]

I've also thought to build it on my own, but I can't believe does not exist something similar, since it should be a common use case in edge-driven IoT scenarios

Answer (score 0):

https://nussknacker.io/ is a rule engine with separated designer and runtime architecture. Given that you can define rule (scenario) and deploy it on your edge device.

Deployment is pluggable ([here](https://nussknacker.io/documentation/docs/developers_guide/Basics#deployment-of-scenarios) is the description how to use your own deployment strategy). Currently there are some ready strategies of deploying those rules: on Apache Flink, as a PODs on K8s or embedded in designer. You can check it as an example in [source code](https://github.com/TouK/nussknacker).

Let's say that your deployment manager just send rule content as a JSON into device. After that you have two options:

- You can run ready runtime - [docker runtime](https://hub.docker.com/r/touk/nussknacker-lite-runtime-app) and binary/java jar runtimes are available
- Use runtime as a [library](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/pl.touk.nussknacker/nussknacker-lite-runtime_2.12) - it is written in scala

Components that will be available to use in rules are also [pluggable](https://nussknacker.io/documentation/docs/developers_guide/Components). There are available some predefined components for filtering, splitting, unions etc.

Rules uses Spring Expression Language - the same as in Apache Camel, but designer is data types aware so you have code completion and validation available.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried Siddhi, https://siddhi.io. It can also be deployed as a Java/Python library

Comment: thank you so much @Niveathika for the tip. Let me check if I've understood How it works: I can define a processing pipeline (eg. pick data from sensor, apply a rule, send events to my broker)  declaratively, then run a processor on edge device as docker container and deploy the pipeline config as a file, so I have to build an automated job that is able to update each device when the configuration is changed

Comment: Yup you can. Siddhi runner will be the processor. You can write siddhi app(s) as per your pipeline (Receive data, process and send data to the broker). This will be loaded to the siddhi runner. Check out the CI/CD pipeline in Siddhi https://medium.com/siddhi-io/building-an-efficient-ci-cd-pipeline-for-siddhi-c33150721b5d

Comment: You can use siddhi tooling for developing the siddhi app https://siddhi.io/en/v5.1/docs/tooling/

Answer (score -1):

Did you take a look at quarkus and its extensions? One of them is camel, which allows you to build simple integration code using an intuitive DSL (http://www.mastertheboss.com/soa-cloud/quarkus/how-to-use-camel-extensions-in-quarkus-applications/) and then you have also the possibility to embed a rule engine inside quarkus (https://quarkus.io/guides/kogito).

Additionally you can build quarkus to run on arm devices as well (aarch64)